# We're trying to build a small dict that's a combination of two others but we're kinda failing

Tags: python

> Write a function `combine_dicts(d1, d2)` that takes two dictionaries
>   as input and returns a dictionary that is a combination of them in the
>   following way:
>
> - If a key is only in one of the dictionaries it should be the same in the result.
> - If a key is in both dictionaries and have the same value (as compared with is in Python) it should be the same in the result.
> - But if a key is in both dictionaries with di erent values, the value in the result should be a tuple with two entires, the one from d1 and
>     the one from d2.
>
> Note that this program doesn’t do anything partic- ular when run. It
>   only exists because it contains this function. The module can be
>   imported in programs that need that function.

So we came up with a pretty simple code, which we don't know if it's correct. We came up with the idea of including two small dicts at the beginning because the assignment provides no way of testing, so we thought if it worked on the dictionaries it would be fine. Things is, it throws error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`. Can you tell us what we're doing wrong?

```
d1=dict()
d1={'1':'uno','2':'dos','3':'tres'}
d2=dict()
d2={'1':'ena', '2':'duo', '3':'tres'}

def combine_dicts(d1,d2):
 d3={}
 for key in (d1, d2):
     # Key is in d1 or in d2
     if key in d1 or d2:
         d3[key]=value
         return d3
     # Key is in both d1 and d2 and values are the same. The below is incorrect right?
     elif key in d1 and d2 and d1[key] is d2[key]:
         d3[key]=value
         return d3
     else:
         if key in d1 and d2 and d1[key] is not d2[key]:
             t=tuple(d1[key], d2[key])
         return t
```

Comment: Hey everyone! Thank you so much for this. I was wondering if you had any material to recommend we could look over when studying dictionaries. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems here.

- Currently in your `for` loop you set `key` to be equal to `d1` and then `d2`, when you want to set it equal to each of the keys.
- You never set `value` anywhere
- You return while processing the first key, and not after having combined the dictionaries, and sometimes you're not even returning a dictionary. You only want to return `d3`, and only at the end.
- There's no need to create the dicts with `dict()` before you create them again with a `{}` expression.
- `key in d1 or d2` will always evaluate to True, because `bool(d2)` is `True`. What you mean to say is `key in d1 or key in d2`. However, you don't really want to have this particular `if` statement at all - all of the keys are from either `d1` or `d2`!

These issues are all fixed below:

```
d1 = {'1': 'uno', '2': 'dos', '3': 'tres'}
d2 = {'1': 'ena', '2': 'duo', '3': 'tres'}


def combine_dicts(d1,d2):
    d3={}
    for key in set().union(d1, d2):
        # Key is in d1 or in d2
        if key in d1 and key in d2:
            if d1[key] == d2[key]:
                d3[key] = d1[key]
            else:
                d3[key] = (d1[key], d2[key])
        elif key in d1:
            d3[key] = d1[key]
        else:
            d3[key] = d2[key]
    return d3

print(combine_dicts(d1, d2))
```

Comment: While I think this is the wrong thing to do, the question does seem to ask for an identity and not an equality comparison ("the same value (as compared with is in Python)").

Comment: To me a comparison of values implies equality, not identity. But this is unlikely to matter, since they don't even have nested lists or dicts to combine, and identity is the same as equality for all objects in the example. @GaaH can weigh in and clarify if they want.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you seem to not understand how to construct a dict:

```
d1=dict() # Construct an empty dict
d1={'1':'uno','2':'dos','3':'tres'} # Construct a dict containing 3 keys/values
```

So you do not need to initialize your variables `d1` and `d2` with `dict()` since the construction `{key: value}` will create a new dict, and thus *overwrite* the previous value (in your case, an empty dict constructed by `dict()`).

Next:

```
for key in (d1, d2):
```

You are asking to iterate over `(d1, d2)`, but `(d1, d2)` is actually a tuple containing your two dicts. So you will go through your loop only two times: one time with `key = d1` and one time with `key = d2`. So the code in your loop cannot work since `key` is a dict and not a key of `d1` or `d2`.

You should first construct a list, or better, a set containing the union of `d1.keys()` and `d2.keys()`. You can do it with:

```
all_keys = set(d1.keys()).union(d2.keys())
```

Then you must iterate over `all_keys` and construct your new dict.

```
for key in all_keys:
    if key in d1 and key not in d2:
        d3[key] = d1[key]
    elif key in d2 and key not in d1:
        d3[key] = d2[key]
    else:
        d3[key] = (d1[key], d2[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here goes. Since an explanation was requested.

- Start with an empty dictionary, *d3*, that will be used as the merged
  dictionary.
- Copy everything from d1 into d3.
- Then for each key in d2:

  - copy the key/value pair into d3 if the key didn't exist in d1.
  - Otherwise, do the special dupe/tuple logic.

Solution:

```
def combine_dicts(d1, d2):
    d3 = d1.copy()  # start by copying the first dict
    for k in d2:
        if (k in d1):
            if d1[k] != d2[k]:
                d3[k] = (d1[k], d2[k])
        else:
            d3[k] = d2[k]
    return d3
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably better to include a little more context/explanation for the code. It's currently in the VLQ queue for whatever reason. (I didn't flag or vote to delete BTW, I skipped).

Comment: Fair enough... done. Longer verbose answers don't always makes for better answers...

Answer (score 0):

here ya go! hope this helps. just a couple for loops to process both dictionaries, the second for loop has the if/else logic to check for matching keys and/or matching values

```
def combine(d1,d2):
    d = {}
    for k,v in d1.items():
        d[k] = v
    for k,v in d2.items():
        if k in d1.keys():
            if d1[k] == v:
                continue
            d[k] = (d1[k], v)
        else:
            d[k] = v
    return d
```